# Get Flutter CupertinoPicker value from Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-listview

I've been struggling to convert the value integer into a string using CupertinoPicker on Flutter, my code looks a bit like this:

```
class AddExerciseMuscleGroupPicker extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddExerciseMuscleGroupPicker({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AddExerciseMuscleGroupPickerState createState() => _AddExerciseMuscleGroupPickerState();
}

class _AddExerciseMuscleGroupPickerState extends State<AddExerciseMuscleGroupPicker> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('MuscleGroups').orderBy('MuscleGroupName').snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _usersStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        return CupertinoPicker(
          itemExtent: 30,
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return Text(data['MuscleGroupName']);
          }).toList(),
          onSelectedItemChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              newExerciseMuscleGroupController.text = value.toString();
            });
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

As it stands, I can create "Muscle Groups" and they will show up on the CupertinoPicker, however, once I pick a "Muscle Group", this returns an integer into the TextEditingController, my question is, How can I return the string instead of the integer? if this approach is wrong I appreciate any small guidance to fix this.
If the list I get is "Chest" "Abs" "Legs", it returns "0", "1", "2" instead of "Chest" "Abs" or "Legs"

Comment: Doesn't `value.toString()` convert integer to string?

Comment: it converts the integer to string, it does not actually give me the value of the list I am picking from.
example, if I pick "Chest", "Abs", "Legs" as a muscle group, it will return "0", "1", "2" and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can set snapshot.data![value] to controller.text.

// You don't have to wrap controller.text value change in setState. It updates the TextField.